# How can I show products from the same category under my product page?

Tags: magento2, product, category, product-page

Under my product page, I wish to have some products shown from the same category.

How can I achieve this in Magento 2 without having to manually set the related products?

Thanks

Comment: You can add Related products

Comment: please specify that is your Version of M1 or M2?

Comment: Edited post with M2. @hewb75 - The point is for Magento to automatically show them by what category they are in rather than me adding related products for thousands of products.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code in your product detail page template.

**For Current product category ids**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/

?>
```

**Load the product by category id**

```
     $categoryId=" Take the id from your current product categories array"
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category= $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($categoryId);
        $collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create()
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
       collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
return $collection;
```

Hope it will help you!